# foreach loop not returning the right value?

Tags: c#, user-interface, foreach, unity-game-engine

Inside a foreach loop that uses a List I call a function but it doesn't return the right value

```
    foreach (var element in cSkillClassArray)
    {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(12.5F, -42.5F + (100 * (element.Id + 1)), 100, 80), "+"))
            {
                windowSkillsAddXPPopupDraw = true;
                windowCDraw = false;
                windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalled(0, element.Id);

            } }
```

The foreach loop calls GUI elements too and they all get drawn with the right elements

```
void windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalled(int languageID, int skillID)
{
    windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalledLanguage = languageID;
    windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalledID = skillID;
}
```

This is the function that gets called inside the GUI.Button call but no matter what GUI.Button in the foreach I press on element.Id seems to send the same as I always end up with the same name which always is "Events"

```
    switch(windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalledLanguage)
    {
        case 0:
            windowSkillsAddXPPopupPoints = programmingExperience_C_Points;
            windowSkillsAddXPPopupSkillLevel = cSkillClassUserArray[windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalledID].Lvl;
            windowSkillsAddXPPopupSkillName = cSkillClassArray[windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalledID].Name;
            break;
    }
```

This is my GUI labels

```
    GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 1F, 470, 40), "Add points to " + windowSkillsAddXPPopupSkillName); 
    GUI.skin = xSkin;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 80F, 500, 50 ), "You got " + Convert.ToString(windowSkillsAddXPPopupPoints) + " points");
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 40F, 500, 50), windowSkillsAddXPPopupSkillName + " level " + windowSkillsAddXPPopupSkillLevel);
```

In both editor and standalone it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think that "gets called inside the GUI.Button call" is a correct description. `GUI.Button` call doesn't go back to the user-space code. Did you mean to write "gets called if the GUI.Button call returns true"?

Comment: Also, I think it would be easier to replace `windowSkillsAddXPPopupRecentlyCalled` method with a simple `Debug.Log` call with the relevant parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have posted a bunch of code and it appears you are implying that something "does not work". You have however not made clear what this code is supposed to do, i.e. what you expected it would do versus what you observe it does. "This code doesn't work. help!" is insufficient information. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: Alex ' This is the function that gets called inside the GUI.Button call but no matter what GUI.Button in the foreach I press on element.Id seems to send the same as I always end up with the same name which always is "Events" '. I don't have enough reputation to posts link to pictures.